# splitting a pandas object

Tags: pandas, object, split

I have a column in dataframe that has values such as 45+2, 98+3, 90+5. I want to split the values such that I only have 45,98,90 i.e drop the + symbol and all that follows it. The problem is that pandas has this data as an object making string stripping difficult any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select first values of lists by indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['45+2','98+3','90+5']})

df['new'] = df['col'].str.split('+').str[0]
print (df)
    col new
0  45+2  45
1  98+3  98
2  90+5  90
```

Or use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for first integers from values:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)')
print (df)
    col new
0  45+2  45
1  98+3  98
2  90+5  90
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda function for doing this.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=['45+2','98+3','90+5'],columns=['col'])
print df1
   col
0  45+2
1  98+3
2  90+5
```

Delete unwanted parts from the strings in the "col" column

```
df1['col'] = df1['col'].map(lambda x:x.split('+')[0])
print df1
  col
0  45
1  98
2  90
```