# pandas replacing the rows value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace values in the rows which contains specific strings

```
    center             
1   /foo/2019
2   /foo/2020
3   /foo/3020
4   /foo/1000
5   900
6   /foo/189098
```

I want to get rid of strings (in this example it is `/foo/`). How can I get rid of them so that I can have this result?

```
    center             
1   2019
2   2020
3   3020
4   1000
5   900
6   189098
```

Thanks!

Comment: same type of problem solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585851/splitting-a-pandas-object/55586528#55586528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function dedidated to replace strings:

```
df.center = df.center.str.replace('/foo/', '')
```

It can contain also `regex` argument, but in your case it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just `split`

```
df.center.str.split('/').str[-1]
1      2019
2      2020
3      3020
4      1000
5       900
6    189098
Name: center, dtype: object
```

Or `lstrip`

```
df.center.str.lstrip('/foo/')
1      2019
2      2020
3      3020
4      1000
5       900
6    189098
Name: center, dtype: object
```

Or `findall`

```
df.center.str.findall('\d+').str[0]
1      2019
2      2020
3      3020
4      1000
5       900
6    189098
Name: center, dtype: object
```

Comment: like rows1 ~ 4, it contains multiple `/` so I guess the first answer won't work this time then?

Comment: Then use `findall` solution @jayko03, it extract the numbers from the string.

Comment: @jayko03 it will work for the since  I slice the last `.str[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

Or we can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.center.str.replace(r'/foo/', '')

1      2019
2      2020
3      3020
4      1000
5       900
6    189098
Name: center, dtype: object
```